# How to add a new item into an specific position of a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-6.0

I have two list of objects(authors1, authors2), notice the authors1 is already sorted by SDATE,
what I want to do is add the authors2 items into authors1 keeping same order, notice that all new items added needs to go to the end of each group of items

```
IList<Author> authors1 = new List<Author>
{
    new Author { Book = "c#", Code="A11" , SDate = 1 },
    new Author { Book = "c#", Code="A22" , SDate = 1 },
    new Author { Book = "c#", Code="A31" , SDate = 1 },

    new Author { Book = "js", Code="B43" , SDate = 2 },
    new Author { Book = "js", Code="B33" , SDate = 2 },
    new Author { Book = "js", Code="B41" , SDate = 2 },

    new Author { Book = "java", Code="C27", SDate = 3 },
    new Author { Book = "java", Code="C33", SDate = 3 },
    new Author { Book = "java", Code="C78", SDate = 3 }
};

IList<Author> authors2 = new List<Author>
{
    new Author { Book = "c#", Code = "A21" },
    new Author { Book = "java", Code = "C23" }
};
```

EXPECTED

```
IList<Author> authors1 = new List<Author>
{
    new Author { Book = "c#", Code="A11", SDate = 1 },
    new Author { Book = "c#", Code="A22", SDate = 1 },
    new Author { Book = "c#", Code="A31", SDate = 1 },
    new Author { Book = "c#", Code="A21", SDATE = 1 },  // new item added to the end of this group

    new Author { Book = "js", Code="B43", SDate = 2 },
    new Author { Book = "js", Code="B33", SDate = 2 },
    new Author { Book = "js", Code="B41", SDate = 2 },

    new Author { Book="java", Code="C27", SDate=3 },
    new Author { Book="java", Code="C33", SDate=3 },
    new Author { Book="java", Code="C78", SDate=3 },
    new Author { Book="java", Code="C23", SDATE=3 }  // new item added to the end of this group
};
```

how can I accomplish this functionality?

I was trying with two foreach, and then push the items into a new list,
please help

```
    IList<Author> response = new List<Author>();

    foreach (var author in authors2.GroupBy(x => x.Book).ToList())
    {
        foreach (var item in author)
        {
```

Comment: What's `SDATE`?

Comment: Is it by intention that there is no `SDate` specified for the elements of `authors2`?

Comment: yes, because we dont know the SDate in authors2, once is added the item into the authors1 also we have to add the SDate value that is in the authors1

Comment: SDate = schedule date, day = 1, 2 ,3,etc

Comment: Not sure if you're not going beyond the purpose of a list here. But you could add an 'AddedTimestamp' and then perform a sorting that first handles the SDates and then as secondary sort uses the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
foreach(Author a in authors2)
{
    Author b = authors1.Where(x => x.Book == a.Book).LastOrDefault();
    if (b != null)
    {
        int index = authors1.IndexOf(b);
        a.SDate = b.SDate;
        authors1.Insert(index + 1, a);
    }
}
```